# Rustup-installed Rust on Fedora: Unable to find Libudev.pc

Tags: fedora, pkg-config, rust

I'm trying to build a rust app on fedora within a rustup environment that depends on libudev. At the moment I get the error when trying to compile the app with `cargo build --release`:

```
error: failed to run custom build command for `libudev-sys v0.1.4`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/home/me/myApp/target/release/build/libudev-sys-7d615f10fc24f9b2/build-script-build` (exit status: 101)
  --- stdout
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=LIBUDEV_NO_PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=LIBUDEV_STATIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=LIBUDEV_DYNAMIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_ALL_STATIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_ALL_DYNAMIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_PATH
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR

  --- stderr
  thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: "`\"pkg-config\" \"--libs\" \"--cflags\" \"libudev\"` did not exit successfully: exit status: 1\n--- stderr\nPackage libudev was not found in the pkg-config search path.\nPerhaps you should add the directory containing `libudev.pc'\nto the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable\nPackage 'libudev', required by 'virtual:world', not found\n"', /home/me/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/libudev-sys-0.1.4/build.rs:38:41
```

In the past things worked fine on ubuntu (or any debian-based, using the system rust install not rustup) after doing `sudo apt install libudev1 && sudo apt install libudev-dev`.

So far, I've tried or considered:

- looking at the advice in [Unable to find Libudev.pc](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/715215/unable-to-find-libudev-pc) , most of that advice was particular to someone's homebrew / linuxbrew setup while this question is specific to Fedora with a Rustup installed rust environment.
- Tried updating my `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` and checking things with `PKG_CONFIG`, specifically:

  1. See where the libraries are via `yum provides */libudev.pc`, which reveals `Filename    : /usr/lib/pkgconfig/libudev.pc` & `Filename    : /usr/lib64/pkgconfig/libudev.pc`
  2. Add the lib folders to `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` in my `.bashrc`: `PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/pkgconfig/:/usr/lib64/pkgconfig`
  3. Start a new shell, run `pkg-config --libs --cflags libudev` , which still gives an error

     ```
      Package libudev was not found in the pkg-config search path.
      Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libudev.pc'
      to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
      Package 'libudev', required by 'virtual:world', not found
     ```
  4. Running `pkg-config --variable pc_path pkg-config` shows `/usr/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/share/pkgconfig`
- considered doing `sudo dnf install libudev` , but hesitate since I'm using a rustup environment instead and installing that triggers installing the fedora system version of rust too.

Answer (score 4):

Doing `sudo dnf install rust-libudev-devel` resolves this, but I'm not personally happy with this answer as doing this requires redundantly installing rust (the fedora package) as well.

Answer (score 3):

Doing `sudo dnf install libudev-devel` (which actually installs `systemd-devel`, at least on Fedora 37) resolves this, without redundantly installing the `cargo`and `rust` and a bunch of other Fedora (instead of `rustup`) packages.