# libudev not found in pkg-config search path in GitHub actions ubuntu-latest environment

Tags: ubuntu, apt, pkg-config, rust

I'm setting up CI for a Rust application I'm developing that (indirectly) depends on the `libudev-sys` crate. Part of this CI means building my crate, which means also building `libudev-sys`.

When the workflow runs and it gets to the build stage, cargo fails with this error message while attempting to build `libudev-sys`:

```
thread 'main' panicked at /home/runner/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/libudev-sys-0.1.4/build.rs:38:41:
  called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value:
  `PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_SYSTEM_CFLAGS="1" PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_SYSTEM_LIBS="1" "pkg-config" "--libs" "--cflags" "libudev"` did not exit successfully: exit status: 1
  error: could not find system library 'libudev' required by the 'libudev-sys' crate
```

```
Package libudev was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libudev.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libudev' found
  note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

I'm struggling to debug this because every change requires committing and pushing to the repo and then waiting for the workflow to run. This is not an error encountered on my own system.

According to [this page about the ubuntu-latest environment](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/main/images/ubuntu/Ubuntu2204-Readme.md), `systemd` is installed (which provides `libudev`), as well as `pkg-config` from `apt` (so [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/715233) in a related question doesn't apply).

I have tried installing `systemd` with `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install systemd`, but that shows that `systemd` is already installed. I also tried updating the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` as per [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/715221), but this did not work either.

Comment: It likely requires the libudev *development* package `libudev-dev` - not just the runtime package `libudev`

Comment: Thanks @steeldriver, that worked! I'll add an answer mentioning that now to make it easier for anyone coming to the question to find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As commented by @steeldriver, it turns out the `libudev-dev` package is required. Installing `libudev-dev` with `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install libudev-dev` did the trick.